# How to generate a triangulation for FEM 1D - MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, triangulation

I'm trying to plot Exact VS FEM solution for this equation:
[image: Equation]

with boundary condition:
[image: Boundary Condition]

I followed this code for example: [Example Code](http://www4.ncsu.edu/~zhilin/TEACHING/MA587/MATLAB/1DSIMPLE/drive.m)

It's fine for its case, but in my case I don't know about how to get the triangulation (for my case) for this line:

```
x(1)=0; x(2)=0.1; x(3)=0.3; x(4)=0.333; x(5)=0.5; x(6)=0.75;x(7)=1;
```

Here is my code:

```
clear all; close all;

x(1)=0*pi; x(2)=0.1*pi; x(3)=0.3*pi; x(4)=0.333*pi; x(5)=0.5*pi; x(6)=0.75*pi;x(7)=1*pi;

U = fem1d(x);

x2 = 0:0.01:pi; k2 = length(x2);
for i=1:k2,
    u_exact(i) = soln(x2(i));
    u_fem(i) = fem_soln(x,U,x2(i));
end

error = norm(u_fem-u_exact,inf)

plot(x2,u_fem,':',x2,u_exact)
hold; plot(x,U,'o')
xlabel('x'); ylabel('u(x) & u_{fem}(x)');
title('Solid line: Exact solution, Dotted line: FEM solution')

figure(2); plot(x2,u_fem-u_exact); title('Error plot')
xlabel('x'); ylabel('u-u_{fem}'); title('Error plot')
```

How to generate the triangulation values? Does anyone know?

Thank you

Comment: @Adriaan Sorry for that, I've edited it.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). What do you mean by "triangulation values"?